# check_mysql_slavestatus RPE: Unable to read output

Tags: nagios, mysql-replication, nrpe

i am using Nrpe plugin on Ubuntu from nagios exchange check_mysql_slavestatus.

Manually its working from :

```
root@Bastion-01:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_mysql_slavestatus -H Slave-ip -P 3306 -u root -p xxxxx -w 10 -c 20

OK: Slave SQL running: Yes Slave IO running: Yes / master: 172.31.20.9 / slave is 0 seconds behind master | delay=0s
```

**Similarly it works from Master DB**

```
root@DB-01:/usr/lib/nagios/plugins# ./check_mysql_slavestatus -H Slave-ip  -P 3306 -u root -p xxxxx -w 10 -c 20

OK: Slave SQL running: Yes Slave IO running: Yes / master: 172.31.20.9 / slave is 0 seconds behind master | delay=0s
```

**Getting Error**

```
root@Bastion-01:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_nrpe -H Master-ip -c check_mysql_slavestatus  
NRPE: Unable to read output
```

**On Nagios Server**

In Command.cfg

```
define command{
        command_name check_mysql_slavestatus
        command_line $USER1$/check_mysql_slavestatus -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -P $ARG1$ -u $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$ -w $ARG4$ -c $ARG5$
}
```

vim /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/nagios_DB1.cfg

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service 
        host_name                       DB-01
        service_description             check_mysql_slavestatus
     check_command check_nrpe!check_mysql_slavestatus!hostname!portnumber!username!passwd!15!50
}
```

**Output On Nagios**

```
check_mysql_slavestatus
CRITICAL    06-09-2015 13:51:51 0d 2h 45m 12s   3/3 (No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/check_nrpe, ...) failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory
```

Please let me know where i am wrong

Followed troubleshooting doc https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/NRPE-Troubleshooting-and-Common-Solutions.pdf

## vim /etc/sudoers

```
nagios ALL= NOPASSWD: sudo /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_slavestatus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't fully understand how NRPE works. You do not have the `check_nrpe` plugin installed on your Nagios server, or the path to it is wrong. It's difficult to say for sure, without seeing your check_nrpe command definition.

Also, you seem somewhat confused about how to pass macros to check_nrpe...

`check_nrpe!check_mysql_slavestatus!hostname!portnumber!username!passwd!15!50` means:

```
ARG1 = check_mysql_slavestatus
ARG2 = hostname
ARG3 = port
ARG4 = user
ARG5 = pass
ARG6 = 15
ARG7 = 50.
```

This is almost certainly not what you intend/want, unless your check_nrpe command takes 7 arguments (unlikely).

Changing that to something like `check_nrpe!check_mysql_slavestatus hostname portnumber username passwd 15 50` would be more correct, but this will only work if you have configured NRPE to match. It must accept command arguments and your check_nrpe command definition must use `-a $ARG1` at the end.

Furthermore, you need to define a `check_mysql_slavestatus` command that uses all of these arguments in the NRPE config on the remote end, not on the Nagios server.

It might help to read the [NRPE documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf) again.